# Не сохраняется или не правильно считывается SharedPreference

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences

При открытии меню постоянно все пункты false или true.

Не могу понять почему,ибо вроде бы всё правильно делаю, но почему-то не сохраняет нужные мне значения или же наоборот не правильно считываются.

1)Открыл меню

[image: Открыл меню]

2)Отключил нужный пункт

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3)Нажал ОК и заново захожу в меню

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код:

```
/*НАСТРОЙКИ+СОХРАНЕНИЕ ИНФЫ*/
public static final String CHECK_SETTINGS = "check_settings"; //Имя файла
//Обучение
public static final String hasWathed="false"; // проверка на просмотр обучения

public static final String notifShops="true"; // уведомления магазинов
public static final String notifWebSite="true"; // уведомления сайта
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        final String[] items = {" Получать уведомления об обновлениях сайта "," Получать уведомления об акциях магазинов "};

        final List<String> colorsList = Arrays.asList(items);

        sp = getSharedPreferences(CHECK_SETTINGS,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        boolean webSite = sp.getBoolean(notifWebSite, false);
        boolean shops = sp.getBoolean(notifShops, false);

        final boolean[] mCheckedItems={webSite,shops};

        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Настройки")
                .setMultiChoiceItems(items, mCheckedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {

                        mCheckedItems[indexSelected]=isChecked;

                        // Get the current focused item
                        String currentItem = colorsList.get(indexSelected);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                currentItem + " " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        /*if(indexSelected==0){
                            Log.d("Settings","notifWebSite"+isChecked);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
                            e.putBoolean(notifWebSite, isChecked);
                            e.commit(); // не забудьте подтвердить изменения
                        }
                        if(indexSelected==1){
                            Log.d("Settings","notifShops"+isChecked);
                            SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
                            e.putBoolean(notifShops, isChecked);
                            e.commit(); // не забудьте подтвердить изменения
                        }*/
                    }
                }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
                        e.putBoolean(notifWebSite, mCheckedItems[0]);
                        e.putBoolean(notifShops, mCheckedItems[1]);
                        e.commit(); // не забудьте подтвердить изменения
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //  Your code when user clicked on Cancel
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                }).create();
        dialog.show();

//        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Settings.class));
        return true;
```

Comment: @TimurVI я не могу его сделать не final, не позволяет android

Comment: @TimurVI не помогло. Я заметил,когда я убираю все галочки,всё сохраняется, когда ставлю все галочки, тоже всё сохраняется,а когда убираю ОДНУ галочку, перестаёт сохранять

Comment: @pavlofff воу,этого я не знал,спасибо!Помогло!
А когда я хочу получить элемент с помощью команды boolean webSite = sp.getBoolean(notifWebSite, false); для чего мы указываем второй boolean параметр?Мы даём ему значение сразу или что?

Comment: это значение по умолчанию, переменная получит его, если в преференсах еще ничего не сохранено под указанной меткой (нет такого ключа)

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас оба значения сохраняются под одной меткой. Не знаю, что вы думали, назвав ключи `notifWebSite` и `notifShops` одним загадочным именем *true*, но если вы хотите, чтобы они хранили разные значения, то имена меток должны различаться.

Это не параметр, а имя, под которым параметр будет сохранен в преференсах